# Is the Facebook HTML5 Like Button supposed to fallback into an iframe? Or is there something going wrong with the rendering?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I've recently noticed that the Facebook Like Button for the Web using the HTML5 code still generates an iframe. Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there some way to disable the iframe so it displays only as an HTML5 button?

Thank you.

Comment: That is for isolation. They don't want you to be able to access the like button.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense.